# down_interruptible in Linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am having some difficulty in understanding the below statement from LDD3. "down_interruptible - it allows a user-space process that is waiting on a semaphore to be interrupted by the user".

A userspace application wont be direclty making the down_interruptible call. Lets say a device driver does and the application is put to sleep by the device driver triggered by a call to down_interruptible. Now how does a signal to the user space application invokes the application from sleep because its the device driver which called the down_interruptible not the application.

Somebody please clarify this to me.

Comment: Read the comment at [`kernel/locking/semaphore.c`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/locking/semaphore.c#L42), and contrast it with `down`. Remember signal handling involves the kernel (for instance, putting a process in the background would have to schedule it, and only the kernel can do that). Is it still unclear? If so, the implementation of [`__down_common`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/locking/semaphore.c#L204) is only a few lines away.

Answer (score 11):

Any device driver does not run of its own, device driver run on behalf of a process via system calls.

Suppose any device driver invokes `down_interruptible();`, it means if semaphore is not available the respective process will be put on the semaphore wait-queue.
And task state will be changed to `TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE` and scheduler will be invoked to run any other process. Now the sleeping process can be woken up either by the event for it waiting (semaphore) or by the signal.

Example: `kill -SIGINT <pid>` will cause the process to change its state to `TASK_RUNNING` and will add the process to run queue.

Here is the pseudo code of wait queue, which shows how a process waits for any event.

```
/* ‘q’ is the wait queue we wish to sleep on */
DEFINE_WAIT(wait);
add_wait_queue(q, &wait);
while (!condition) /* condition is the event that we are waiting for */
{
    prepare_to_wait(&q, &wait, TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);
    if (!signal_pending(current))
    {
        schedule();
        continue;
    }
    ret = -ERESTARTSYS; 
}
finish_wait(&q, &wait);
```

In your example the process is added to wait queue and waiting for the condition to release it. Meanwhile it checks for any pending signal also, if there is any, it will return `-ERESTARTSYS`, otherwise again go for sleep.

Comment: `it checks for any pending signal also, if there is any, it will handle the signal and again go for sleep` - No, *signal handling* is **not performed** when waiting event. When signal arises, interruptible waiting just returns `-ERESTARTSYS`, which is usually propagated by the driver's code to the caller. Signals are handled on returning from the system call itself.

Comment: @Tsyvarev yes you were right , signal are only handled when returning from system call,  earlier i was referring to Linux Kernel Develoment Book by robert love page 59                                                                  "If the state is set to TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE, a signal wakes the process up.This is
called a spurious wake up (a wake-up not caused by the occurrence of the event). So check and handle signals."

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Again I have a doubt here. When we call prepare_to_wait and then call schedule, the process goes to sleep. Now the condition that it is waiting for is tested within the same process. So how does the condition process come out of sleep.?

Comment: When  semaphore get releases by another process then wake_up will be issued to the sleeping process ... It will change the task state of the sleeping process to TASK_RUNNING then the sleeping process will be added to run queue ... When it will get chance to run it will test condition and will come out of loop.